# Consulta MySQL sin datos al añadir más criterios de búsqueda

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me devuelva los registros de acuerdo a los valores de programa estado y fecha pero solo me muestra los nombres de las columnas, pero los datos no.

Con 2 criterios de búsqueda me muestra los datos sin ningún problema, pero lo quiero hacer con tres criterios y ahí es donde ya no me muestra nada.

Pongo la consulta:

```
SELECT IL.Cliente, CA.Programa, IL.Estilo, IL.Color, SUM(IL.Total) AS 
Pares, CA.Material, CA.Departamento, CA.Fecha_Pago AS Fecha_Pedido
FROM compras_ange AS CA 
INNER JOIN infolote AS IL ON CA.Programa = IL.Programa 
WHERE CA.Programa LIKE '%10493%'
AND CA.Estado = 'En Espera' 
AND (CA.Fecha_Pago BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-01')
GROUP BY CA.Material, CA.Programa, CA.Departamento;
```

Comment: has probado quitnando los parentesis? si  solo muestra los nombres de las columnas es porque np hay datos que cumplan la condicion

Comment: Quiere decir que no tienes resultados para el día '2018-10-01'. Si la fecha de inico del intervalo es la misma que la del fin es mejor usar = en lugar de between. Los paréntesis no son necesarios, pero no afectan al resultado.

Comment: Si, tienen razon, perdon, error mio, mas es cambiar el AND por un OR

Answer (score 0):

Aunque MySQL te permite ese tipo de agrupamiento es posible que te la consulta te devuleva incoherencias. Para saber si tu consulta si te devuleve resultados y el efectivamente el error esta en el agrupamiento le quitas el GROUP BY y el SUM.

Yo te recomiendo que ejecutes la consulta asi:

```
SELECT IL.Cliente, CA.Programa, IL.Estilo, IL.Color, CA.Material, CA.Departamento, 
 CA.Fecha_Pago AS Fecha_Pedido, SUM(IL.Total) AS Pares
FROM compras_ange AS CA 
  INNER JOIN infolote AS IL ON CA.Programa = IL.Programa 
WHERE CA.Programa LIKE '%10493%'
  AND CA.Estado = 'En Espera' 
  AND (CA.Fecha_Pago BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-01')
GROUP BY IL.Cliente, CA.Programa, IL.Estilo, IL.Color, CA.Material, CA.Departamento, 
  CA.Fecha_Pago AS Fecha_Pedido;
```